# Как получить все символы после какого либо знака на jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть элемент с классом `font-family=arial` и я хочу получить значение, которое идет после `=`, затем применить полученное свойство на этот же элемент.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232462/get-value-from-a-string-after-a-special-character

Comment: что за класс такой font-family=arial не валидный